# Component to short 2 wires when powered

Tags: transistors, short-circuit

I am attempting to short 2 different wires, call them A and B when C I'd powered. I am attempting to use a transistor, but when I attatch C to the base and A or B to the emittor, it just powers A/B which isn't what I want, I need A/B to be shorted. Is there a way to configure a transistor to do this? Or might I need a relay of some sort?

Comment: How is C connected/related to A or B otherwise?

Comment: C is connected to a form of input, when the input is HIGH I need to short A and B, which operate on a separate circuit.

Comment: Is the answer then "it is completely independent"?

Comment: Yeah it is independent

Comment: Try a transmission gate? http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~jones/es154/lectures/lecture_4/mosfet/mos_circuits/mos_circuits.html

If you do this you need to feed your turn on signal to the gate of one NMOS and pass the inverted signal to the PMOS. 

What are A and B connected to? Are you trying to switch a power supply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a relay - the relay contacts are totally isolated from the controlling source so there is no chance of introducing unwanted voltages, and no need to be concerned with the polarity between the points you want to short (although you do have to select a relay whose contacts can handle the voltage and current that may be encountered.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with a transistor? I'd prefer not to have to go drive down to the electronics store again :P if not then I'll grab a relay tomorrow

Comment: For lower voltages, a digitally controlled SPST switch, also called a bidirectional bus driver or an analog multiplexer, will do quite well without wearing out from motion fatigue the way a relay will.  (For an example with more "throw" states, [ADG804 from Analog Devices](http://www.analog.com/ADG804))

Comment: If the voltages on A and B have a known relationship to C, then a transistor or analog switch may work, but you have to watch the polarity, and have some knowledge of the circuit that A and B are part of.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this --

1) As previously mentioned, you could use a relay; this would provide a direct short as you require, and would allow a substantial current to flow between the shorted leads as necessary.  The disadvantage is it is fairly large compared to other methods, and requires comparatively more power to turn on the relay, likely requiring a BJT or MOSFET transistor driver.

2) You could use a pair of MOSFETs to bridge the two leads.  This is small, cheap, can also handle quite a bit of current, and doesn't require hardly any power to activate it.  However there will be a finite resistance between the two leads (R\$_{ds}\$ On of the transistor).  This can be the the milliohms, so it probably won't be an issue.

[image]

3) A third way is to use an analog switch, which is particularly design for this purpose, (connecting two leads together). is an analog switch such as the [Maxim MAX4626](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX4626-MAX4628.pdf).   It has an on resistance of about 0.5Ω, and can handle up to 400 mA continuous.  The downside (if it matters) is that the voltages on the leads to be shorted must not exceed the supply voltage (typically 5v) + .3V.

[image]

Comment: In option #2, you really should connect the sources together, not the drains. This makes it easier to drive the two gates in parallel relative to their common source connection.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thank you.  I just copied the first figure I could find under bidirectional MOSFETs.  I'll try to find one with S/D reversed.

Comment: One caveat with the first approach -- the gate drive needs to be referenced to the source node.  This practically means you need an isolated driver for the FET pair -- usually transformer or photovoltaic-isolator based.

Answer (score 0):

If the current in A/B is DC and reasonably low enough and you have an optocoupler somewhere around that might work as well.